# While Installing the the Netbeans 12.5 to my window pc I am getting error msg in the path setting

Tags: java, netbeans

I am getting error message **"the specific jdk folder contains jdk version 2724.0.0.0.0 while the maximum is 500.0.0.0.0"**.

Image of the specific error provided:

[image]

Comment: What is the output of `java --version` if you run this in `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-17\bin`. Which java distribution did you install in this directory?

Comment: java 17 2021-09-14 LTS
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 17+35-LTS-2724)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 17+35-LTS-2724, mixed mode, sharing)

Comment: the above is the output. and I basically know that it is running perfectly

Answer (score 1):

That seems to be a known bug: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/NETBEANS-6043

And as it seems you can work around it changing the JDK manually in `etc/netbeans.conf`